# Div does not follow drag-bar when moving

Tags: javascript

Im trying to add a drag handle to an div , but the div doesn't  move, just the handel.

But if I change the position to position absolute to the div that are supposed to move, I can actually move around the div, but from everywhere and not just the drag handle.

Any tips ? I created a jsfiddle for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/dymond/tQdFZ/11/

Some code.

```
var draggable = document.getElementsByClassName('hand'),
        draggableCount = draggable.length,
        i, currZ = 1;
    function startDrag(evt) {

        var diffX = evt.clientX - this.offsetLeft,
            diffY = evt.clientY - this.offsetTop,
            that = this;
        this.style.opacity = "0.5";
        this.style.zIndex = currZ++;

        function moveAlong(evt) {
            that.style.left = (evt.clientX - diffX) + 'px';
            that.style.top = (evt.clientY - diffY) + 'px';
        }
        function stopDrag() {
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveAlong);
            document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
            changeClass()
        }
        function changeClass() {
            var diceClass = document.getElementsByClassName("hand");
            for (var i = 0; i < diceClass.length; i++) {
                diceClass[i].style.opacity = "1";
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveAlong);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < draggableCount; i += 1) {
        draggable[i].addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting css:

```
.draggable { position: absolute; ...
```

and change js:

```
function moveAlong(evt) {
    that.parentNode.style.left = (evt.clientX - diffX) + 'px';
    that.parentNode.style.top = (evt.clientY - diffY) + 'px';
}
```

Since you want to move the parentNode, by draging the handle..

Comment: Thanks. I thinks its the second time you help me out :)